# Why can I not assign `cls.__hash__ = id`?

Tags: python, class, attributes

I would have hoped this works (in Python 3.6),

```
class A:
    __hash__ = id
A().__hash__()
```

but I get

```
TypeError: id() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

Surprisingly,

```
def my_id(self):
    return id(self)
class A:
    __hash__ = my_id
A().__hash__()
```

works as hoped.

Comment: It's not just `__hash__`. You'd get the same with a normal method. I think that `id` as a built-in-function, doesn't quite follow the same rules as a function written in Python.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`id` is of type `builtin_function_or_method` (it's a function that's built into the runtime - ), which for practical reasons (optimisation mainly) doesn't implement the `descriptor` protocol as a python function would, so `A().__hash__` resolves to the `id` function itself, not to a `method` object wrapping the function.

You'll observe the same behaviour with most builtin functions FWIW:

```
>>> type(len)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>> len.__get__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__get__'
>>> 
>>> type(all)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>> all.__get__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__get__'
>>> type(abs)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>> abs.__get__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__get__'
>>> type(isinstance)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>> isinstance.__get__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__get__'
```

etc...